# I am a Sheikh and I need to answer someone's question

Tags: forgiveness

A man came to me after salat Al Juma, and asked me a question. He said, " when I was a teenager, I saw a naked lady during her shower ( on purpose )without her knowing." He said that he "loved" that lady. He then said that he asked God for forgiveness, and never committed any other major sin till now. He said, "will Allah forgive me?" I didn't know what to tell him, so is there anyone that can help me answer his question?

Comment: I need someone to answer my question please, may Allah forgive all Muslims...

Comment: If you don't know than you'd better say so. Nobody knows (with certainty) whether or not Allah will accept any of our deeds or repentance as we don't know what Allah has decided for us in future. Read also [this post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46775/13438), [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/47202/13438) and many more.

Answer (score 2):

Sure He does, if ...

> إِنَّمَا التَّوْبَةُ عَلَى اللَّـهِ لِلَّذِينَ يَعْمَلُونَ السُّوءَ
> بِجَهَالَةٍ ثُمَّ يَتُوبُونَ مِن قَرِيبٍ فَأُولَـٰئِكَ يَتُوبُ
> اللَّـهُ عَلَيْهِمْ ۗ وَكَانَ اللَّـهُ عَلِيمًا حَكِيمًا ﴿١٧﴾
> وَلَيْسَتِ التَّوْبَةُ لِلَّذِينَ يَعْمَلُونَ السَّيِّئَاتِ حَتَّىٰ
> إِذَا حَضَرَ أَحَدَهُمُ الْمَوْتُ قَالَ إِنِّي تُبْتُ الْآنَ وَلَا
> الَّذِينَ يَمُوتُونَ وَهُمْ كُفَّارٌ ۚ أُولَـٰئِكَ أَعْتَدْنَا لَهُمْ
> عَذَابًا أَلِيمًا ﴿١٨
>
> The repentance accepted by Allah is only for those who do wrong in
> ignorance [or carelessness] and then repent soon after. It is those to
> whom Allah will turn in forgiveness, and Allah is ever Knowing and
> Wise. (17) But repentance is not [accepted] of those who [continue to]
> do evil deeds up until, when death comes to one of them, he says,
> "Indeed, I have repented now," or of those who die while they are
> disbelievers. For them We have prepared a painful punishment. (18)
>
> [An-Nisa]

Indeed, He further has revealed:

> قُلْ يَا عِبَادِيَ الَّذِينَ أَسْرَفُوا عَلَىٰ أَنفُسِهِمْ لَا
> تَقْنَطُوا مِن رَّحْمَةِ اللَّـهِ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّـهَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ
> جَمِيعًا ۚ إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْغَفُورُ الرَّحِيمُ ﴿٥٣﴾ وَأَنِيبُوا إِلَىٰ
> رَبِّكُمْ وَأَسْلِمُوا لَهُ مِن قَبْلِ أَن يَأْتِيَكُمُ الْعَذَابُ
> ثُمَّ لَا تُنصَرُونَ ﴿٥٤﴾ وَاتَّبِعُوا أَحْسَنَ مَا أُنزِلَ إِلَيْكُم
> مِّن رَّبِّكُم مِّن قَبْلِ أَن يَأْتِيَكُمُ الْعَذَابُ بَغْتَةً
> وَأَنتُمْ لَا تَشْعُرُونَ ﴿٥٥﴾ أَن تَقُولَ نَفْسٌ يَا حَسْرَتَىٰ
> عَلَىٰ مَا فَرَّطتُ فِي جَنبِ اللَّـهِ وَإِن كُنتُ لَمِنَ
> السَّاخِرِينَ ﴿٥٦﴾
>
> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by
> sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives
> all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful." (53)
> And return [in repentance] to your Lord and submit to Him before the
> punishment comes upon you; then you will not be helped. (54) And
> follow the best of what was revealed to you from your Lord before the
> punishment comes upon you suddenly while you do not perceive, (55)
> Lest a soul should say, "Oh [how great is] my regret over what I
> neglected in regard to Allah and that I was among the mockers." (56)
>
> [Az-Zumar]

May Allah forgive all of us for all wrong-doings we may have committed, knowingly or not knowingly

Answer (score 0):

If someone repents and never come backs to sin again Allah will surely forgive him no matter how big the sin was. Zazakallah khair