# How one can become a self learned scholar of Islam?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis, islamic-scholar

How one can become a self learned scholar of Islam?

Comment: A starting point is: [What are the minimum requirements for someone to be a “student of knowledge”?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46735/what-are-the-minimum-requirements-for-someone-to-be-a-student-of-knowledge)

Comment: Self learning is not -always- recommended, see: [Are we discouraged from reading tafseer without an 'alim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33343/are-we-discouraged-from-reading-tafseer-without-an-alim) and [Am I allowed to study and read ibn qayyims books without an ustadh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46880/am-i-allowed-to-study-and-read-ibn-qayyims-books-without-an-ustadh).

Comment: To add to what @Medi1Saif said that is because the 'alim will add context to the tafseer